# Is Consistent Hashing the implementation of peer to peer distribution model?

Tags: nosql, riak

As I know there are two model for replication/sharding -> Master/Slave and p2p.

So is consistent hashing (e.g. used by Dynamo or Riak) the implementation of the p2p model?

Answer (score 1):

Riak have masterless replication model, so every node could accept any request. Basically, you could store any data more than once on different nodes by tuning `n_val`. All requests going to any node, and this node route it further to [`r`](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/#Reading-Writing-and-Updating-Data) nodes. This nodes is chosed by [consistent hashing function](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/theory/concepts/#Clustering), applied to key.

[image]